# How to conditionally remove vowels from pandas dataframe columns?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a simple dataframe df:

```
{'Testingthislongcolumnthatwouldbreakoracle': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3},
 'goodcolum': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
 'goodcolum2': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2}}
```

I am trying to determine if the length of the column is > 30, and if so, check to see if removing the vowels will make length of the column <= 30.  If so I'd like to then strip the vowels out of the column name and save it back to dataframe. Here is what I have so far:

```
for columnName in df:
    charlength=len(columnName)
    vowels=sum(list(map(columnName.lower().count, "aeiou")))
    if charlength >= 31:
        if charlength - vowels <= 31:
             df[columnName] = df.columns([columnName]).str.replace('[aAeEiIoOuU]', '')
            
    print(columnName, charlength,vowels)
df
```

But this isn't making any changes.  the end result would change the column 'Testingthislongcolumnthatwouldbreakoracle' to 'Tstngthslngclmnthtwldbrkrcl'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a list with the new names for the columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Testingthislongcolumnthatwouldbreakoracle': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3},
 'goodcolum': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
 'goodcolum2': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2}})

col_names = []
for columnName in df:
    charlength=len(columnName)
    vowels=sum(list(map(columnName.lower().count, "aeiou")))
    if charlength >= 31:
        if charlength - vowels <= 31:
          col_names.append(''.join(char for char in columnName if char not in 'aeiouAEIOU'))
    else:
      col_names.append(columnName)   
    
print(df)
df.columns=col_names
print(df)
```

Comment: No reason to cast `"aeiouAEIOU"` to a `set`, it's already iterable and comprised of unique values.

Answer (score 0):

The `str.replace()` function doesn't work like that. You need to replace each vowel with the empty string individually:

```py
>>> s = "Testingthislongcolumnthatwouldbreakoracle"
>>> for vowel in "aeiou":
...     s = s.replace(vowel, "")
...
>>> s
'Tstngthslngclmnthtwldbrkrcl'
```

Also, just a heads up, you don't need to cast your `map` to `list` before summing the results. Would actually be more efficient to

```py
s = columnName.lower()
vowel_count = sum(s.count(v) for v in "aeiou")
```